# How to expose a web-service with cxf:proxy-service

Tags: java, proxy, cxf, mule, callable

I am trying to expose a simple greeting web-service using "cxf:proxy-service" in mule. Given below is my flow.

```
<flow name="WS_In">
    <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/HelloService" exchange-pattern="request-response">
        <cxf:proxy-service  wsdlLocation="classpath:HelloService.wsdl" namespace="http://example.org/HelloService"/>
    </http:inbound-endpoint>        
    <component>             
        <prototype-object class="com.example.ServiceProxy">
        </prototype-object>
    </component>

    <echo-component></echo-component>
    <logger level="INFO"        />
</flow>
```

But it giving me error as below:

```
2013-01-03 16:13:35,569 ERROR [main] construct.AbstractFlowConstruct (AbstractFlowConstruct.java:180) - Failed to stop service: WS_In
org.mule.api.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Lifecycle Manager 'WS_In.stage1' phase 'start' does not support phase 'dispose'
```

My ServiceProxy calss is as below

```
public class ServiceProxy implements Callable, Initialisable
```

Please help me understand where I am missing the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out ...

1. Get the service name from your WSDL and use it in cxf:proxy-service
2. User the class direclty in component.

....

```
<flow name="WS_In">
    <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/HelloService" exchange-pattern="request-response">
        <cxf:proxy-service  wsdlLocation="classpath:HelloService.wsdl" namespace="http://example.org/HelloService" service="HelloService"/>
    </http:inbound-endpoint>        
    <component class="com.example.ServiceProxy" />
    <echo-component></echo-component>
    <logger level="INFO"        />
</flow>
```

Comment: No Luck. It gave exception                                org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'name' is not allowed to appear in element 'cxf:proxy-service'.

Comment: My bad. Corrected my response above to use service instead of name.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of attribute 'name' in `<cxf:proxy-service>` element, use attribute 'service' to specify service name.